# Flexbox layout issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to figure out how to build the layout seen in the screenshot attached using Flexbox or any other tool.? The main issue is aligning the buttons from different content containers along the same axis. Is it possible to do using current Flexbox workflow and properties.? Let me know if you need more info. Help is much appreciated.

[image: layout example]

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, so if you want a proper answer, provide the effort you made so far and update the question with the code, and we'll see how we can assist.

Comment: I haven't actually built it, but here's a quick jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/418xwcyj/8/ . Basically, I want the top of the tiles to always align, and the buttons to align at the top along the same axis as in screenshot, no matter how much content there is in either content block or inside the button.

Comment: With that code sample, the duplicate links explain both why and how to solve your question.